# select objects in array using date comparsion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write my own query/filter function for my AngularJs app.

I have a JSON with a lot of posts like this

```
[
{
    "date": "20100101",
    "keyword": "blah",
    "header": "My header",
    "text": "aaa, bb, c, dd. ee f g h."
},
{
    "date": "20110101",
    "keyword": "blah-hah",
    "header": "Your header",
    "text": "foo and bar and then some"
}
```

]

In my app I have a small form where the user enters "date from", "date to", and then optionally a keyword.

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateFrom">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dateTo">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="keyword">
```

The user add his/her criteria and push a button, my fabolous function loops through the JSON and all posts with a date between the criterias (if entered), and a matching keyword (if entered), will have their "text" property added to a string, bound to textarea for show.

To me, it looks like a simple loop where I check the given criterias, but how do I handle the date comparsion in a sane way? using Date.Parse()? Or are there any Angular helpers?

Regards

Comment: There are lots of other questions about comparing dates for you to find an answer on, but the general jist is to convert both dates to a javascript date object and compare the two using `.getTime()` which ensures you are comparing two millisecond representations of the date.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there are no shortcuts, not to smooth so I thought Angular perhaps had a cleaner solution. But if that's the way to do it, then I will, thanks :)

Comment: Saying that your using `"date" : "20110101"` in your JSON so you could manipulate the user entry to match that format of date and test on string comparison `userDate === yourJSON[i]["date"]`.

Comment: @Mark, yes I thought about that but I'm not sure if that will work good enough comparing >= dateFrom and <= dateTo.. I'm not that comfortable with javascript yet.